# ElasticSearch count how many users only one doc?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

How can I use `aggregations` in ElasticSearch to count how many users only have one doc in the database?

```json
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "users_with_single_doc" : {
            "rare_terms": {
                "field": "uid",
                "max_doc_count" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query above can only list all buckets with `_doc_count` is 1, but I want to count how many buckets which has `_doc_count` is one.

Answer (score 0):

[The rare_terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-rare-terms-aggregation.html) is a type of value source aggregation used in Elasticsearch to identify infrequent or rare terms in a set of documents. It is similar to the terms aggregation, but instead of sorting the terms by count, it sorts them in ascending order of rarity. This means that rare terms that occur infrequently in the dataset are given higher priority and are returned first. The rare_terms aggregation is a more accurate way of identifying rare terms than sorting by count, which can have unbounded errors.

You can use the terms aggregation and [bucket_selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) for your case. Here is an example:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "final_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.values == 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beware, though, that the top 10 terms might not be the buckets with doc_count = 1 and hence the response might be empty. It really depends on the cardinality of tags, so you might need to increase the size of the terms aggregation to at least the cardinality of tags.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly, to count the number of buckets what about using the [stats bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html)?

Example:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "users_with_single_doc": {
            "rare_terms": {
                "field": "uid",
                "max_doc_count": 1
            }
        },
        "stats_users_with_single_doc": {
            "stats_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "users_with_single_doc > _count"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and what if the `users_with_single_doc` is connected to a date range aggregation and the `stats_users_with_single_doc` aggregation generate stats data for each date range bucket?